# Async : Get empty array after For inside the callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I try to store the result of a DB query in an array but I always got an empty array. I don't understand very well how Async works but I think this code should be work because I store The variable before It finish

**Note:** following is an array also and I understand this problem is because Async behavior but I dont know what to do to solve it

code:

```
    exports.getfollowingUser = function(req, res){
  followedUser=[];
  following = req.user.follow;

  for (i = 0; i < following.length; i++) { 
    User.find(following[i].followed, function (err, followUser){
    followedUser[i]= followUser;
    });
    }
    console.log(followedUser) // result empty
    res.render('following', {
      followedUser: followedUser 
    });
  };
```

**EDIT :1**  Follow schema

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Friendship',{

    follower: String,
    followed: String
});
```

**EDIT :2**  User schema

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('User',{

    email:{
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true },

    password:String,

    profile:{
        fullname: String,
        gender: String,
        role: {type: String, default: 'Autorizado'},
        country: String },

});
```

**Note:** I'm trying to get the friends that the User (Login) is following and show them in a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for loop `node` just make request to your DB and continue processing. It doesn't wait for result from database. This is how async works. So after your for loop `node` didn't yet receive results from DB and `followedUser` is empty. To fix this without third-part libraries you can do:

```js
exports.getfollowingUser = function(req, res){

    findFollowedUser(req.user.follow, function(error, followedUser) {
        console.log(followedUser);
        res.render('following', {
            followedUser: followedUser
        });
    });

    function findFollowedUser(following, callback) {
        var followedUser=[];
        var waiting  = following.length;
        var wasError = false;

        for (var i = 0; i < following.length; i++) {
            User.find(following[i].followed, function (err, followUser){
                if (wasError) {
                    return;
                }

                if (err) {
                    wasError = err;
                    return callback(err);
                }

                followedUser[i]= followUser;
                waiting--;

                if (!waiting) {
                    callback(null, followedUser);
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Another way (and I think better) is to use some flow control libraries. For example:

- [q](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q)
- [bluebird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird)
- [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async)
- [fibers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fibers)

My personal preference: [bluebird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird) - extremely fast promise realization. Actually *promises* is upcoming standard of javascript. So I'd recommend you to take a closer look at it.

Also I'd recommend you to watch [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ). This is very simplified explanation of javascript async model (how event loop works).

Comment: @jose-osorio You are welcome). Also I forgot: look at [ECMAScript 6 Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the flow of execution:

```
exports.getfollowingUser = function(req, res){
    followedUser=[];                                                  // 1
    following = req.user.follow;

    for (i = 0; i < following.length; i++) {                          
        User.find(following[i].followed, function (err, followUser){  // 2,3,4
            followedUser[i]= followUser;                              // 7,8,9
        });
    }
    console.log(followedUser) // result empty                         // 5
    res.render('following', {followedUser: followedUser});            // 6
};
```

As you see, at the time of your `console.log` [5], `followedUser[i]= followUser` hasn't yet executed [7,8,9]. This is why you're getting the empty array.

Here's how you could fix it

```
exports.getfollowingUser = function(req, res){
    followedUser=[];                                                  // 1
    following = req.user.follow;

    var counter = 0;
    var length = following.length;

    for (i = 0; i < following.length; i++) {                          
        User.find(following[i].followed, function (err, followUser){  // 2,3,4
            followedUser[i]= followUser;                              // 7,8,9
            counter++;
            if(counter>=length) allDone();                            // 10
        });
    }

    console.log(followedUser) // result empty                         // 5
    res.render('following', {followedUser: followedUser});            // 6        

    function allDone(){
        console.log(followedUser) // result empty                     // 11
        res.render('following', {followedUser: followedUser});        // 12       
    }
};
```

Here the same statements but inside the `allDone()`[11,12] will do what you're expecting them to do, as they execute after [7,8,9].

This is just to explain, there are better libraries to handle stuff like this:

- Async: https://github.com/caolan/async#each
- Promises: https://gist.github.com/neilk/8467412

Also helpful: https://blog.engineyard.com/2015/taming-asynchronous-javascript-with-async

Comment: how can I use promises or Async. Do you have a reading or something  ? note: let me check the code